# How to use the chipmunk physics-engine?

Tags: iphone, physics, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game demo where I want a physics simulation with balls and obstacles.

I know that this is possible with the chipmunk physics-engine but I don't know how to use it. Can anybody give me suggestions how to get started and provide links to the API documentation?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use chipmunk in general, or just the collision-detection part of chipmunk?

Comment: Yes I want To Know How TO Use The Chipmunk

Comment: I Want TO  know That how To Add This Api To My Project And how Can I Define As Per My Requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search gave me these two links.On which platform you need?

http://code.google.com/p/grabbed/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk  [Sample done with ChipMunk]

http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/articles/chipmunk/ [detailed description on usage ]

Comment: in the second link i  am adding the all file named the demos still it want need Few More header  to include